# kill multiple process in linux using perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I have multiple running process that has a name of cpu2006.
I try to kill all of the process using one command in linux:

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep cpu2006 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

And it works.

The problem is when I try to use Perl script:

```
system("kill -9 `ps -ef | grep cpu2006 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`");
```

It doesn't work.

Can someone correct my code?
Your help is very much appreciated

Comment: You should really be using [`pkill(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill) instead of `ps(1)`.  See also [Bash pitfall #31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#ps_ax_.7C_grep_gedit).

Comment: thanks Adam Rosenfield

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to kill it using pkill. Because cpu2006 is the name of the path and under cpu2006 there is a lot of process name. Different process name represents different test. For example the first test is perlbench_base and after it has finished there will be another test perlzip.

Comment: Please add `use warnings; use strict;` to the top of your script. Hopefully the problem (if not the answer) will then become more apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what "*It doesn't work.*" looks like (error messages? silent failure?), whether the script is running with permissions sufficient to do the kill, what surrounding code exists in the script, and so on.

However, there is one glaring issue:  You're using double-quotes.  Double-quotes allow for variable interpolation.  So the `$2`, which I believe you intend to be populated by `awk`, is being interpolated as a Perl variable, which probably contains an undefined value.  That undefined value (undef) gets concatenated into the string such that what your shell sees is something like this:

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | grep cpu2006 | grep -v grep | awk '{print }'`
```

(Note that the $2 has been replaced by Perl with an empty string, which is the stringified version of an undefined value.)

To solve *that* problem, don't use double quotes.  And since you already need literal single quotes within the string, the easiest alternative is the `q/..../` quote-like operator.  Use it like this:

```
system(q/kill -9 `ps -ef | grep cpu2006 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`/);
```

It's unclear to me whether this will solve all of your problems, but it will solve one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Proc::Killall](http://search.cpan.org/~jwb/Proc-ProcessTable-0.50_01/Killall.pm) module. It supports pattern matching also.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Sanket Parmar :). I've gotten my answer :)